# Display Maximum Value For Each Day (python)

Tags: python, graph, max, min

i'm using python 2.7.3

How can i find & display the maximum value of my txt file for each day

```
TimeStamp,Irradiance,Ambient_Temperature
21/7/2014 0:00,0.66,29.16
21/7/2014 0:00,0.71,29.16
21/7/2014 0:00,0.65,29.17
21/7/2014 0:00,0.67,29.17
21/7/2014 0:01,0.58,29.17
.
.
.
22/7/2014 23:58,0.69,28.54
22/7/2014 23:58,0.61,28.54
22/7/2014 23:58,0.65,28.51
22/7/2014 23:58,0.59,28.54
22/7/2014 23:59,0.63,28.55
22/7/2014 23:59,0.67,28.54
22/7/2014 23:59,0.68,28.56
22/7/2014 23:59,0.58,28.55
```

This is how i find the max/min of the days for irrad & temp (not one day) so how can i do it roughly the same way as the code below for finding just one day rather than over few days

```
long_title = ('\n Max Irrad Value: {:.2f} at {} , Min Irrad Value: {:.2f} at {}, Max AMB_TEMP Value: {:.2f} at {} , Min AMB_TEMP Value: {:.2f} at {}\n')
ax1.set_title(long_title.format(max(temp),min(temp),fontsize=16, color='green',ha='bottom'))
```

thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {}
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        date, rest = line.split(None,1)
        time, irrad, temp = rest.split(',')
        irrad = float(irrad)
        temp = float(temp)
        if time not in data:
            data[time] = {'maxTemp':float('inf'), 'minTemp':float('-inf'), 'maxIrrad':float('inf'), 'minIrrad':float('-inf')}
        if irrad < data[time]['minIrrad']:
            data[time]['minIrrad'] = irrad
        elif irrad > data[time]['maxIrrad']:
            data[time]['maxIrrad'] = irrad
        if temp < data[time]['minTemp']:
            data[time]['minTemp'] = temp
        elif temp > data[time]['maxTemp']:
            data[time]['maxTemp'] = temp
```

`data` now contains the max and min temperature and irradiation for each day

Comment: hi, thank you very much for replying, i appreciate your help, i have updated my full code on the OP, how can i write it to be fit into my code

Comment: @toothberry: Sorry, that's out of my league. Perhaps `pandas` could help, but I've never used it, so I wouldn't know